# How to make a request like: "limit(n-records) or as many existing records. AR is looping.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have something I believe is very common and has a simple solution.

What I want is a request like...

**"give me 10 records unless it's the end of records, then give me just the rest of results".**

Consider a db-table with **105 records**. 
and a request like

```
User.first.foos.offset(100).limit(10)
```

This request will give me a result of...

```
recored: 100
recored: 101
recored: 102
recored: 103
recored: 104
recored: 105
recored: 1
recored: 2
recored: 3
recored: 4
recored: 5
```

What I want is just records 100, 102, 103, 104, 105

**How can I make limit to not loop and give me records in the beginning?**

Is it a RoR way to do this or do I have to count all records to and change the limit value based on the number of records?

Comment: I just have tried same query in Rails 5.0 and this works fine, without loops. What Rails version are you using? Also please write the code of your models and the sql queries from log.

Comment: Do you have an `order` condition on your `has_many :foos` relation?  Or a `default_scope` that has an `order` condition in your Foo model?

Comment: Thanks for that. It seams like order does the trick.